# Protractor doesn't uphold chromium switch `--host-resolver-rules`

Tags: google-chrome, protractor

When I run protractor with the `--host-resolver-rules` in the `capabilities.chromeOptions.args`, I see that it opens a child process with my rules in the switches:

`/home/me/my-proj/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --enable-automation --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-logging --host-resolver-rules="MAP * XX.XX.XX.XX" --load-extension=/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.u8z24y/internal --log-level=0 --no-first-run --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=0 --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp`

However, the browser doesn't actually resolve requests to my rule's IP address `XX.XX.XX.XX`. The switch appears to be completely ignored.

When I copy-paste the foregoing command into my shell, though, the newly-opened chromium instance successfully resolves all requests to my IP address `XX.XX.XX.XX`.

What do I need to do to make hostname resolution work in Protractor?

*Chromium 80.0.3987.0* 
*Protractor 5.4.4* 
*Puppeteer 2.1.1*

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this, getting the same kind of error using Watir/Ruby/Chromium